# IP for online users. 

Tags: php, session, cookies, ip

I was wondering how to get the current users online and their IP address.

I know  how to get a clients IP adress and I know how to use cookies and sessions for current users.

What i need is the logic to get the IP of the current user, and if the user leaves the site, it will stop tracking the users and stop getting the users IP.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can't say when a user leaves a site. You can only say when you've seen that user the last time (and then specify a time-out). Also please search the site, how to handle that has been asked and answered earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `print_r($_SERVER)` - there's loads of info in there about the current user.

If the user leaves the site, you can't detect that immediately - but you can keep a track of the last time you saw a user in your database, and if you don't see a user for (say) 20 minutes, invalidate their cookie.

Edit: one thing you could do is have a periodic AJAX operation that says 'this user is still here' every 30 seconds or so. However this arguably puts more stress on your web server than is necessary - the earlier option I outline is probably better.

Comment: there is a paid service from http://www.newrelic.com that you should look into, it provides server monitoring and live user tracking. they're quite pricey and require root level access to your server to install the daemon. I use them across 3 of my VPS servers to monitor them.

Answer (score 1):

You can get ip of user using this

```
$ipAdrressOfUser=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```